# Which one would be efficient design for firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I tried to design a book sharing app. A user can enroll in different group and share his books. Each book contains field **currentGroupId** and **ownerID**.
I need to show all books of a user and all books shared in particular group. Will it be efficient to keep all books together? Or should I keep books under each group and user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
  books: {
    1: { _id: 1, userId: 10, groupId: 10 }
  },
  users: {
    10: { _id: 10 }
  }
}
```

so

```
const booksFromUser = firestore.collection(`books`).where(`userId`, `==`, WHATEVER_USER_ID)

const booksFromGroup = firestore.collection(`books`).where(`groupId`, `==`, WHATEVER_GROUP_ID)
```

that should give you a starting point, it's a common pattern :), I wouldn't even create a group collection if you really dont need it.